# Is it possible to run a build for particular change in Gatsby Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, devops, gatsby

When I run the build for Gatsby project it is taking more than **1.30 HR** because of lot of lot of dynamic pages. My question is when I make a change on a particular page or pages Is it possible to run the build for the particular changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `gatsby develop` try using [Gatsby flags](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/#flags). Used like this in the `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  flags: {
    FAST_DEV: true,
  },
}
```

You can find a full detailed explanation of the current available flags at: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/src/utils/flags.ts

In your case, try using `FAST_DEV` which includes    `PRESERVE_FILE_DOWNLOAD_CACHE` and `DEV_WEBPACK_CACHE` flags respectively.

For `gatsby build` I think you are looking for a feature called Incremental Builds: which basically only builds the pages that have changed from the last deployment.

Depending on your deploy server there's a different implementation way:

- Netlify: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/23/enable-gatsby-incremental-builds-on-netlify/
- Gatsby Cloud: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2020-04-22-announcing-incremental-builds/
- Custom implementation: this is difficult to handle without a server implementation, which will be different in each case (and details have not been provided in the question). Try adapting Netlify's answer by enabling `GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES` and [`cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), leaving your deploy command like:

  ```
   "build": "cross-env GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages"
  ```